How to compute $\operatorname{Length}(k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]/I)$ for some ideal $I$
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $\mathcal{O}_0=k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ be the ring of formal power series, $I$ be an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_0$ such that $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_0/I)$ is zero dimensional, i.e. $\mathcal{O}_0/I$ is finite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space. Suppose we have a set of generators $f_1,\dots,f_m\in \mathcal{O}_0$ of $I$, are there any algorithms that can compute $k[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]/I$?
Intuitively it should be decided by "lower terms" of $f_i$, which is the upper convex hull of Newton polygon. So are there local versions of BKK theorem?
